# How to set JLabel value from TextFile?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a file named `easyscore.txt`

Text is written in the notepad once the player enters his name in this program.

Here's my code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You win the easy difficulty :D", "Congrats", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
String easyname=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter player name"); 
try {
      FileWriter easyscore = new FileWriter("easyscore.txt");
      PrintWriter peasyscore = new PrintWriter(easyscore); 
      peasyscore.println(easyname);
      peasyscore.close();
}
catch(IOException e) {
    out.println("ERROR!");
}  
MinesweeperXHighscore MinesweeperXHighscore = new MinesweeperXHighscore();
MinesweeperXHighscore.setVisible(true);
```

The other java class `MinesweeperXHighscore` contains labels.

From the start the labels will be empty (no text) and the name will be added to the label once the player entered it at the end of my game.

MinesweeperXHighscore Code:

```
private void Easyscorer() {
    String n1;
    try {
        FileReader feasy = new FileReader("easyscore.txt");
        BufferedReader breasy = new BufferedReader(feasy);
        n1 = breasy.readLine();
        while (n1 != null) {
            INVILABELEASY.setText(n1);
        }
        breasy.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        out.println("ERROR!");
    }
}
```

where `INVILABELEASY` is the `JLabel` that I tested.

I input a username while testing, but the label is still empty.

When I check my text file the name that I entered was there so the problem is
 that the `JLabel` is still empty and does not read from the text file well.

Comment: Consider providing a comilable and runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: Variable names should not be all upper case characters. Follow Java conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change this peace of code:

```
while(n1!= null)
       {
        INVILABELEASY.setText(n1);
       }
```

to :

```
if(n1!= null)
           {
            INVILABELEASY.setText(n1);
           }
```

Your code is in a infinite loop because `n1` is always not null

Here is the `easyscore.txt` file

[image]

And here is the `MinesweeperXHighscore` java frame

[image]